# How can I create a pull request with github api?

Tags: github

The API is : `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/pulls`.
I used the correct token, and the request body is :

```
data = {
    "base": "master",
    "head": "owner:master",
    "title": "title",
}
```

The head is like this:

```
{'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json', "Authorization": "token {}".format(git_token)}
```

Then I call the pull API. Returned 200.

```
<Response [200]>
```

Why? Maybe the request body wrong?

Comment: 200 means ok. Google http status codes

Comment: The information the server gives you is in the body of the response I assume

Answer (score 0):

The [Pull Request API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls#create-a-pull-request) specified the answer:

```
Status: 201 Created
```

Try and anddapt their example to your repository, to see if it does work:

```sh
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/pulls \
  -d '{"head":"head","base":"base"}'
```