# Merge multiple branches into master and create a new branch with the result

Tags: github

I have a master branch with main code.
I have created several branches which each branch have a new feature.

```
-> Master
-> Feature 1
-> Feature 2
...
-> Feature 80
```

I have an idea to create a simple web-page where the users can choose which features they want to include. Then I want to merge all selected features (branches) into the master and create a new repository on Github that the user can access.

Does anybody have any ideas if this is possible using Github's features, have any other approach on this matter or do I have to code this manually myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webapp could create a PR (Pull Request) through an [GitHub API call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69188021/6309), one PR per selected branch.

Then the "[enable auto-merge for PR](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/automatically-merging-a-pull-request)" feature from GitHub would automatically merge each of those PR, provided there is no conflict.
Or you can use the [`merge-pull-requests-automerge-action`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/merge-pull-requests-automerge-action) GitHub action.